# How can I point the frontend dir in config/production.json

Tags: reactjs, feathersjs

I'm changing the configuration of the public dir to point to a create-react-app generated build dir. The app show up but the API is not available any more. 
What did I do wrong?
Is there any way to change the api path to /api instead?

```js
    //dafault.json
    {
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 3030,
      "public": "../public/",
      "paginate": {
        "default": 10,
        "max": 50
      },
      "authentication": {
        "secret": "FAKE secret",
        "strategies": [
          "jwt",
          "local"
        ],
        "path": "/authentication",
        "service": "users",
        "jwt": {
          "header": {
            "type": "access"
          },
          "audience": "https://yourdomain.com",
          "subject": "anonymous",
          "issuer": "feathers",
          "algorithm": "HS256",
          "expiresIn": "1d"
        },
        "local": {
          "entity": "user",
          "usernameField": "email",
          "passwordField": "password"
        }
      },
      "mongodb": "mongodb://localhost:27017/scm"
    }

    //production.json
    {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": "PORT",
        "public": "../src-front/build/"
    }
```

Comment: That shouldn't affect the API (unless there are folders with the same names as your services). Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I've found the issue : it was related to the front configuration and not to feathers itself. I've set public to the build dir of the React App and it works.